# Does stochastic independence imply that there is no relationship between variables?

Tags: stochastic-processes, relations, independence

I am wondering if it is possible for data to be stochastically independent while still having a relationship between the variables?

Just an example let us assume we have data points that have no stochastical independence but we can still find an equation that is relating the variables by $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (points are lying on a circle). I know that points on the circle might be correlated. I just wanted to make clear what I am asking, at least I hope I could make that clear :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but this example comes to my mind. Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables. Define the sample mean
$$
\bar X_n=n^{-1}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)
$$
and the sample variance
$$
S_n^2=(n-1)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X_n)^2.
$$
Denote
$$
Z=(\bar X_n-\mu)n^{1/2}/\sigma
$$
and
$$
V=(n-1)S_n^2/\sigma^2.
$$
$Z$ and $V$ have $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in their expressions and it seems that they should be dependent. However, they are independent. The ratio $Z/\sqrt{V/(n-1)}$ has Student's $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Derivation) for more details).

I hope this is useful.

Comment: + 1 For your answer. But I must admit that I will have to think about your answer for some time in order to fully understand it :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath I don't think that it is very easy to show that $Z$ and $V$ are independent. However, at least the idea should be clear. If we know the values of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, we can evaluate $\bar X_n$ and $S_n^2$. So intuitively it seems that they should be dependent because they are expressed in terms of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. However, it is possible to prove that they are independent.

Comment: More simple we can say that random variables $U:=X_1+X_2$ and $V:=X_1-X_2$ are both expressed in $X_1,X_2$ but are independent if $X_1,X_2$ are iid and are normal. This especially because by normality a zero covariance implies independence.

Comment: @drhab and CM7F7Bb. Thank you for your help. Now it is clear.